# Is Q isomorphic to Q(π) as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I guess that $Q$ and $Q(\pi)$ are not isomorphic as fields. And I know $Q(\pi)$ is isomorphic to $Q(x)$. So it seems to suffice to show that $Q(x)$ is not isomorphic to $Q$ as fields.

But I really don’t know how to show two fields are not isomorphic.

My trial was to find a polynomial that has roots in $Q(x)$, but not in $Q$. Sadly, I couldn’t come up with anything.

Can somebody help me?
Thank you.

Comment: They are not isomorphic. There are no non-trivial sub-fields of $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: Ohhhhh thanks! I have one more question. What if Q is replaced by any field $K$? Is it still true that $K$ and $K(x)$ are not isomorphic?

Comment: No, you can have $k(x)$ isomorphic to $k$ for some fields $k$.  ($\mathbb Q(\pi)\cong \mathbb Q(x)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas Andrews notes in the comments, $\mathbb Q$ is a nontrivial subfield of $\mathbb Q(\pi)$, but $\mathbb Q$ has no nontrivial subfields. However, there do exist fields $K$ for which $K$ and $K(x)$ are isomorphic: consider
$$K=\mathbb Q(x_1,x_2,\dots)$$
consisting of all rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ and countably many variables $x_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$. There is an isomorphism between $K$ and
$$K(x)=\mathbb Q(x,x_1,x_2,\dots)$$
given by $x_1\to x$, $x_2\to x_1$, $x_3\to x_2$, etc.

Comment: Oh, that’s great! Thanks. Then if the variables are finitely many, the result is different?

Comment: @ylh0501 If you adjoin finitely many variables to $\mathbb Q$ (without any specific equations the variables should satisfy), then the results shouldn't be isomorphic unless you adjoin the same number of variables. Take a look at the concept of transcendence degree.

Comment: Ohh OK! Thank you for the reference!